# How to list all NTFS and share permissions associated with a user or security group?

Tags: active-directory, network-share, file-permissions, windows-sbs-2003

We are doing some tidying up of Active Directory on our SBS 2003 domain controller.

A number of security groups exist which I am 95% sure are redundant. I want to be 100% sure they are not used anywhere before I delete them.

I would like to find a way to produce a *comprehensive* report listing all NTFS and share permissions associated with either a user or security group. Presumably I need a 3rd party program to do this?

Has anyone here done something like this before?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Surely someone has some thoughts on this?

Comment: You might want to try AccessEnum http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332.aspx

Comment: That's exactly the sort of thing I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I'll post that as an answer so you can accept.

Comment: AccessEnum seems to have quite a basic interface- there could be better options out there. It could be quite difficult for me to use on our server with 720GB of data (mostly consisting of small documents). If no one else chimes in with any better answers then I'll accept this one next week :)

Comment: you can check windows built-in icacls.exe, but I don't believe you will like that interface

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [AccessEnum](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332.aspx)